# what is the best way to avoid Open Redirects in django

Tags: django, apache, redirect

e.g. If the following redirects to evilsite.com from mysite.com
[https://www.mysite.com/http:%5C%5Cwww.Evilsite.com](https://www.mysite.com/http%3a%5C%5Cwww.Evilsite.com)

I am using django 1.4 hosted on apache using mod_wsgi (latest version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django can not prevent all open redirects attacks automatically.

As a workaround, Django provides a helper function [django.utils.http.is_safe_url](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3259983f569151232d8e3b0c3d0de3a858c2b265/django/utils/http.py#L331). You need to check the url manually before passing the url to the redirect function. Don't implement your own your own function. Even the django core developer did not implement it correctly at the first place. Check this [security release](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/aug/13/security-releases-issued/).

Reference:

[Avoid open redirect issue with whitelist](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13751)

[Put protection against unsafe redirects into `HttpResponseRedirectBase`](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19992)

Comment: Since Django 3.0, `is_safe_url` is deprecated, replaced by [`url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/http.py#L302) in `django.utils.http`.

Comment: And note that url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme is still not safe! On top of using the new function, `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`, you should also be sure to encode your URL with the `urlencode` filter.

Comment: @mlissner What's the reason it's not safe to just do `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`? (without `urlencode`)

Comment: My bad – I found the answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60372947/118608