# When do you need to use iri_to_uri after using url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme in Django?

Tags: django, redirect, iri

In the [Django 3.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#id3), this comment is made about `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`:

> To avoid possible confusion as to effective scope, the private internal utility `is_safe_url()` is renamed to `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme()`. That a URL has an allowed host and scheme doesn’t in general imply that it’s “safe”. It may still be quoted incorrectly, for example. Ensure to also use [`iri_to_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.iri_to_uri) on the path component of untrusted URLs.

I understand what the purpose of `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme` is. Take the common use-case of providing a `next` query parameter, for example: http://example.com/foobar?next=http%3A%2F%2Fexample2.com%2Fhello . You could program the view that handles this path to redirect to the URL provided by the `next` parameter, in this case: 
http://example2.com/hello . If the URL is not validated, then this is an "open redirect" vulnerability. Malicious actors could take advantage of an open redirect to hide malicious URLs behind a URL that looks trustworthy.

You can use `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme` to ensure that the URL has the expected hostnames and scheme.

My question is concerning `iri_to_uri`. The documentation implies that you also need to use this function as well. When would I need to use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you would implement a safe redirect:

```py
from django.utils.http import url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def example_view(request):
    if url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme(request.GET['next'], None):
        url = iri_to_uri(request.GET['next'])
        return redirect(url)
    else:
        raise
```

The `iri_to_uri` part is necessary to make sure that the end-result URL is quoted correctly. For example:

- the original URL is something like http://example.com/foobar?next=%2Fcaf%C3%A9%2F
- `request.GET['next']` is equal to `'/café/'`
- `iri_to_uri(request.GET['next'])` is equal to `'/caf%C3%A9/'`

The first line in the HTTP request needs to be in a format like this:

```
GET /caf%C3%A9/ HTTP/1.0
```

The URL needs to be escaped there, as it would break the HTTP protocol if it contained something like spaces.

To be honest, I'm still not entirely sure why `iri_to_uri` is needed, because Django's utilities like `redirect` will automatically escape the URL as needed before it ever gets to the wire in the HTTP request.

Comment: Doesn't the `None` in `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme(request.GET['next'], None)` mean that there are no allowed hosts?

Comment: @Programming123 It means only URLs like `/article/one` are allowed (as opposed to `http://example.com/article/one`), I think.

Comment: that helps very much - I hadn't even thought of that, but switched to full urls due to using a URL field on the form. That solves many things, thank you!