# Cannot import is_safe_url from django.utils.http , alternatives?

Tags: python, django, django-4.0

I am trying to update my code to the latest Django version, The method is_safe_url() seems to be removed from new version of Django (4.0). I have been looking for an alternative for the past few hours with no luck. Does anyone know of any alternatives for the method in Django 4.0?

Comment: m voting to close this question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

in Django 3.0 they have renamed `is_safe_url` to `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`. Here you can read more about it [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.0/#:%7E:text=To%20avoid%20possible%20confusion%20as%20to%20effective%20scope%2C%20the%20private%20internal%20utility%20is_safe_url()%20is%20renamed%20to)

Comment: Thank you, seems I missed that part of the doc. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

I think it [has been renamed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#id3) `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme()`. You may also be interested in [When do you need to use iri_to_uri after using url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372946/when-do-you-need-to-use-iri-to-uri-after-using-url-has-allowed-host-and-scheme-i)